# White Balance Algorithm Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, lighting, cielab

I've got a little problem with my color detection app for Windows Phone 8. 
The color of an object strongly depends on light that strikes it. Changing the light source, the color may alter. That's why I wanted to know if there is a way to dynamically know the kind of white balance used by the camera when taking a picture. In this way I could calculate the ΔE (in CIELAB color space) using the correct lighting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need this property [KnownCameraPhotoProperties.WhiteBalancePreset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.knowncameraphotoproperties.whitebalancepreset%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Also consider using [Nokia Imaging Sdk](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Imaging_API_Ref/nokiagraphicsimaging-namespace/whitebalancefilter-class.html) - really neat library.

Comment: Thanks crea7or but this properties is useless if I set white balance in Automatic mode!!And in this last case I want know the white balance used by the camera!!Are there another ideas?